# How to effect an element outside of a div on hover

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm trying to make a sub-menu appear outside of the elements div that I'm going to be hovering. I've tried multiple things to get this work, but I've had no luck so far. The submenu needs to be outside of the links div for designs purposes.

What's the best method to get this to work?

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.nav {
  max-width: 1100;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

.nav a {
  margin: 0 35px 0 0;
  color: #333333;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

#sub-menu {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background: #333;
  height: 150px;
  display: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.three:hover #sub-menu {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="nav">
    <a class="one" href="#">Home</a>
    <a class="two" href="#">About</a>
    <a class="three" href="#">Services</a>
    <a class="four" href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
  <div id="sub-menu"></div>
```

Comment: Preserving your HTML, there is no way to do that without nesting the links with the submenu. CSS cannot go up in a div and the links are in a lower level than submenu. You can try a different approach using event listener in JavaScript, like `onmouseover` event.

Comment: In your case, even if the sub-menu pops up, you wont be able to reach to it as the hover will be over when you mouse out of it.  I would suggest you having submenu inside the element you want to hover on, and then may be position it outside the nav.

Comment: You'll need to use JavaScript here to make it work, but as stated above do you have a good reason to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour cannot be achieved by css alone, you need some JS code.
Here's why:
To ease out this situation, CSS provides 3 selectors

> To apply style changes to children of a div
>   + To apply style changes to the immediate child of the parent div
>   ~ To apply style changes to all the following children of the parent div

But there isn't a way to directly modify the divs two levels up (grandparents :P) using these selectors...so you may need a bit of JS
Hope I answered this question correctly

Reference
https://techbrij.com/css-selector-adjacent-child-sibling

Comment: Thanks for the advice.